# How can I use an $n$-input neural network to predict some values for $n-1$ inputs?

Tags: neural-networks

I have a fully-connected neural network whose input is a vector of $n$ (normalized) integers. Each of these integers is associated with an object. The output is similarly a vector of $n$ values each of which is the prediction of a metric corresponding to one of those objects. The network is trained using the data of all $n$ objects.

Now, I need to consider the prediction scenario above in a faulty manner, say, a fault just eliminates one of those objects. Now, I am wondering whether or not I can use the very neural network above to predict the features of the remaining $n-1$ objects. In particular, I don't who what I need to feed into the input associated with the eliminated object.

Any thoughts and ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You could have an additional $n$ binary inputs which indicates whether each object is present or not.

Alternatively, you could have an architecture which can take in a variable number of inputs and produce a variable number of outputs. For example, given inputs $x_i$, embed them to $z_i = f(x_i)$, then let $z = \sum_i z_i$, and have output $y_i = g(x_i, z)$, where $f$ and $g$ are both neural networks. This scheme doesn't rely on there being any fixed number of objects.

Comment: Can you explain how the second approach can be implemented, e.g., in keras?

Comment: $f$ and $g$ can just be keras layers or modules (or whatever the name for it is, i'm not super familiar with keras). Then you can define your keras model which invokes $f$ and $g$ and carries out the computation.

Comment: The point is that one can train a network based on a fixed architecture, right? If so, how does the network adapt iteself to the variation of inputs and outputs? If you know any example, I shall be grateful if you put its link here.

Comment: i'm not sure i follow the question - there's no requirement that neural networks have a "fixed" architecture. all you need is the ability to compute the gradient of the loss wrt the parameters, which is possible in this setup